# Safest way to parse url for PHP CMS?

Tags: php, security, content-management-system

As an exercise I am rolling my own CMS to better learn php. Currently I have my .htaccess file set to redirect all URLs to the index.php page.

```
// .htaccess file 
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule !\.(js|gif|jpg|png|css)$ index.php
```

Once I am at the index.php page, I will need to determine what content the user should see based off the requested URL. For example, if the user visited `mysite.com/about` then I would be including the file contents of `about.php`.

My question is: what is the safest way to parse this URL for the file value? I want to avoid the user writing malicious URLs which, among other things, could access private php files I don't want shown.

Comment: What is the current code you have adopted to perform this task?

Answer (score 1):

Your htaccess has really nothing to do with security. I suggest you use switch case like this:

```
$site = "home";
switch(strtolower($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])){
  case "about":
    $site = "about";
    break;
  case "contact":
    $site = "contact";
    break;
}
include "{$site}.php";
```

or maybe this:

```
$site = "home";
$page = strtolower($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
switch($page){
  case "about":
  case "contact":
    $site = $page;
    break;
}
include "{$site}.php";
```

Or without having to make list of allowed pages

```
$path = "pages/";
$page = trim(strtolower($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']),"/");
$slashPos = strpos($page, "/");
if($slashPos!==false){
    $page = substr($page, 0, $slashPos);
}
$page = preg_replace("/[^a-z0-9-]/", "", $page);
if(file_exists("{$path}{$page}.php")){
    include "{$path}{$page}.php";
}else{
    //include "{$path}home.php";
}
```

Comment: This is making limitation to sections or pages of the CMS.

Comment: Yes it is, OP didn't say if it's a problem or not